# Errors with Arel query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I'm trying to build a query with Arel with Rails 6 API. I've found [this howto](https://github.com/rstacruz/cheatsheets/blob/master/arel.md) that looks great but I'm getting errors. Though the examples were created many years ago and based on few searches, things looks the same. I have a simple module class:

```rb
users = ::MyModule::User.arel_table
query = users.where(users[:name].eq('amy'))
```

After I ran `query.to_sql`, I see in the rails console:

```sh
"SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'amy'"
```

That's incorrect. I'd expect to see:

```sh
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'amy'"
```

The "all", `*`, is missing. Is this a bug that I should raise? Because its missing the "*", my queries are failing.

Today is my first day using Arel.

Comment: See https://buildingvts.com/intro-to-arel-542a078028aa, you can use `users.project(Arel.star).to_sql`

Comment: If you're using `Arel` to learn it, awesome! If you're looking for suggestions for idiomatic Rails/ActiveRecord then using Arel for this is likely overkill.

Comment: @melcher that gives `*`. You want `users[Arel.star]`.

Comment: @melcher I use it to build a query before performing any db queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Arel what you want to select:

```
users = ::MyModule::User.arel_table
query = users.project(users[Arel.star]).where(users[:name].eq('amy'))
```

Although it would be a lot easier to just use the ActiveRecord query interface which will parameterize it:

```
query = ::MyModule::User.where(name: 'amy').arel
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = ?
```

Comment: Thanks! I see not websites that mentioned "Arel.star". Why? An older version of Arel? Well that works. I choose Arel because I'm building a query and would not want to perform any db queries until the query is finalised.

Comment: Using activerecord (e.g. `::MyModule::User.where(name: 'amy')`) only evaluates the db query "lazily", e.g. when you iterate through the results / explicitly ask for it. So you can finalize the query and then iterate through the results either way. Activerecord uses Arel under the hood so the behavior is very similar from that respect.

Comment: Right! Thanks for that.

Comment: Arel.star just returns `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("*")`. I really wish they would just add add a `#star` method to Arel::Table so you could just write `project(users.star)`. In general Arel is a very powerful but very clunky tool with an aweful API and documentation. Most real world problems are better solved with a combination of AR and Arel.